# Помогите найти ошибку в решении задачи на GO

Tags: golang

Я пытаюсь решить на Go эту задачу:

> Маша создала массив из **n** чисел от 1 до **n**. И какие-то из них поменяла
> на другие, также от 1 до **n**. Напишите функцию `FindMissingValues(nums []int) []int`, которая принимает данный массив и возвращает массив,
> содержащий числа, которые пропали, в порядке возрастания.

Я не особо понимаю что именно в алгоритме у меня не так. Выводит `3 4 5 6`, хотя должно выводить `5 6`.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func FindMissingValues(nums []int) []int {
    n := len(nums)
    missingValues := make([]int, 0)

    expectedValues := make([]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        expectedValues[i] = i + 1
    }

    sort.Ints(nums)
    sort.Ints(expectedValues)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        check := false
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            if nums[i] == expectedValues[i] {
                check = true
            }
        }
        if !check {
            missingValues = append(missingValues, expectedValues[i])
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(nums)
    return missingValues
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(FindMissingValues([]int{4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1}))

}
```

Comment: А для чего вам нужен цикл по j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм логично вывел сравнение слайсов:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] - missingValues
[1 2 2 3 3 4 7 8] - expectedValues
```

- видите, именно `3, 4, 5, 6` - не на своем месте.

Теперь поищите каких цифр из `3, 4, 5, 6` нет в `expectedValues` и получите корректный результат.